# jQuery .text() is not showing emoji

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding, emoji

Let's say I insert a title with the following emojis and jQuery's `.text()`:
❤

The ❤ will show nicely as a Red Heart

shows as ?

shows as ??

Using `.html()` works fine, but I would rather not for security reasons. Same with using javascript `innerHTML`.

Are there any other options that are lightweight enough to just handle emoji? Perhaps a library that can map the emojis into text form?

Comment: What emoji library did you use?

Comment: @JustinPaulPaño what do you mean by emoji library? User selects emojis from their phone keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From plain JS:

```
document.getElementsById('CONTAINER_ID').textContent = CONTENT;
```

This seems a little glitchy at times, but for the most part it works with the above tested emojis and others.